# HttpEntity.getContent() Progress Indicator?

Tags: android, multithreading, streaming, progressdialog

Is there any way in android API 7+ that I can report on the progress of a call to `HttpEntity.getContent()`?

In my case I am getting an image in the response stream so the transfer can take quite a while. I want to have a `ProgressDialog` with the style set to `STYLE_HORIZONTAL` be updated with the progress of the transfer.

Any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `HttpEntity.getContentLength()` to help you predetermine the size of the file? If you use that in conjunction with something like AsyncTask's onProgressUpdate(), you should be able to implement that.

Take a look at this link

[Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog/3028660#3028660)

It has pretty much what you're looking for. it uses urlConnection to get the InputStream so you would need to adapt that to use HttpEntity. So maybe you'd have something like this.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
    int count;
    long contentLength = <yourHttpEntity>.getContentLength();
    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(<yourHttpEntity>.getContent());
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/your_photo.jpg");

    byte data[] = new byte[1024];

    long total = 0;
    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        total += count;
        publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/contentLength));
        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }

    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();
}
```

and update your dialog in onProgressUpdate.

Comment: You should indeed give credits to the author of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog/3028660#3028660) answer.